# Can't call inline javascript function from external scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, external, inline

I declared a function in a inline script at the beginning of my body tags.
Then in an external script. On a form submit. it trigger an anonymous function
that handle data from the form and submit a $.ajax method. The external script is called at the end of the file

The problem is that I assigned a function name in my form tag as a 'data-success="functionName"'. It does trigger the function in the external script.
But the external scripts doesnt recognize the inline function called in the html file.

Here an exemple.
https://jsfiddle.net/vsbmn8w1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vsbmn8w1

HTML

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // The Inline function that dont get called externally
    function searchResult(data) {
      alert()
    }
});
</script>

<!-- Trigger On Submit -->
<form method="post" class="async-form" data-success="searchResult">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

EXTERNAL SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("submit", "form.async-form", function(event) {
  // Declare form in a variable
  var $this = $(this);

  // Prevent Page reloading
  event.preventDefault();

  // Collect Form parameters
  var action = $this.prop('action');
  var method = $this.prop('method');
  var form = $this.serialize();

  // Default request object
  var request = {
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: form
  };

  // Adding parameter to the object if data exist
  if (typeof $this.data('success') != 'undefined') {
    request['success'] = $this.data('success');
  }
  if (typeof $this.data('error') != 'undefined') {
    request['error'] = $this.data('error');
  }
  if (typeof $this.data('beforeSend') != 'undefined') {
    request['beforeSend'] = $this.data('beforeSend');
  }
  if (typeof $this.data('complete') != 'undefined') {
    request['complete'] = $this.data('complete');
  }

  // Finally make the ajax request
  $.ajax(request);
})
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `searchResult` is a local within your `ready` callback, it's not accessible from outside that `ready` callback.

You could make it global by moving it out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...anything that needs to wait goes here...
});

function searchResult(data) {
  alert()
}
```

...and then it would be accessible to code outside that callback (such as in your other scripts).

But globals are a Bad Thing™. :-) You might look at [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or similar packaging/bundling systems that let you write discrete script files with dependencies, but without using globals, by using an import mechanism. (It's even possible to use the new `import` and `export` mechanism defined in ES2015+ [aka "ES6"] if you use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) and one of those bundlers.)